# Should I stay focused on desktop development or learn more about web application development?

Tags: programming-languages

Let me introduce myself a bit.

1. I have 7 years of C++ (most MFC) experience, 1 year C#.NET and 2 years Java experience.
2. I know little about web application, what I did and am doing is Windows desktop applications.

I start to do some (minor) (freelance) side projects in the past half year and uses C# mostly as it's more "rapid" than MFC. But seems there's more web projects in this market than desktop projects. And I do not feel good as long as I do not know web development.

So, should I touch the new web filed for me or just stay focus in desktop application but learn more e.g Python, or Frameworks/Libraries such as Qt or Boost?

Answer (score 6):

My gut feeling is that more and more people/companies are moving their projects to the web. My company, for example, has added numerous web applications since I have been there. Another prime example of this is Microsoft (yes, even them) providing a web-based version of Office, their flagship product.

There will always be a need for desktop applications, but I see more web-based projects in the future. It's always good to learn something new, anyway.

EDIT: Oh, and you don't lose anything by being aware of "desktop-based" processes. You may be doing more server-side programming, even if it is web-based. So, in other words, it doesn't hurt to continue expanding your knowledge in that arena, as well.

Answer (score 3):

There will most likely still be a market for desktop applications for many years to come. However, web development seems to have taken over a large share of the development market from what I can see. I would recommend definitely getting familiar with web development as it definitely can't hurt to increase the number of skills you have even if you never stop writing desktop apps.

Since you have experience with C# you might want to consider doing some ASP.NET work. Or if you feel the need to learn a new technology then maybe consider a framework like Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 3):

I'd really suggest looking into web development - like you said, there are many more web application projects - and you already know C#.NET and Java, and both of those languages have really good API's / frameworks for web development.  ASP.NET for C# and Java Servlets/JSPs.

I'd first suggest learning some really basic HTML to learn how pages are rendered, then try to make dynamic versions using the language of your choice.  Then I'd learn some other web technologies like CSS/Javascript/some Javascript libraries - then I'd start looking at frameworks that build on top of the basics in the language of your choice.

Oh, and some further suggestions - there are web frameworks that are component-based rather than request-based - you may be tempted to learn these as a shortcut to web development since most claim that developing in them is similar to desktop development.  I really wouldn't suggest this - as in practice you really do need to know how the web works at a lower level to develop custom components, include things that the framework doesn't do, or to debug them when things go wrong even when using these frameworks.  If you jump right in you can get lost/confused pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Office 2010 will have an [online version](http://www.centernetworks.com/microsoft-office-2010-web-apps). To me this is a watershed moment for Web applications. Office apps are an important litmus test as once you can do Office on the Web (which has been the case with Google Documents for some time but Office has important symbolic meaning) you can do most things that most users care about.

Desktop apps won't die but I definitely think they're going to take more and more of a backseat.

I'd highly suggest you read [How Microsoft Lost the API War](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/APIWar.html) if you haven't already. One of the things that's particularly amazing about this post is that it was written in 2004.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly believe that with maybe the exception of OSs and browsers, everything will be a web app within the next 10 years. Having said that, let me clarify that by everything I mean everything that a) involves a UI of some kind and b) can be guaranteed secure.

User-interfaced apps will always at some point need a backend, which will at some level require code that is not being interfaced by humans and not being executed via HTTP. I am always reminding myself that things like 'cat' in Unix are actually programs that the OS is calling, not just a function built into the OS. MySQL won't be a web app (as far as I know), but app that powers web apps. We may get to a point where these apps are fully developed via a web interface, written, audited, uploaded and called all via a browser, but at some level its still running behind the scenes.

On that second point, about guaranteed security, I can very easily imagine a large corporation or government office running 95 percent of their daily routines via web apps, but mandating that certain high-security operations be done on a machine directly interfaced with some sort of mainframe, after passing through the cool doors with the retinal scans and what not. Or simply because they can't risk moving certain mission-critical apps over to the web, from fear of it breaking our losing data in the process.

But with those two things aside, I honestly believe everything will be web-based. With the advancement of Web Services and XML in general, it will be possible to not only access and interact with our data, but to plug our custom apps into another app and extend that interaction further and in any environment we want.

It's like that Apple ad "There's an app for that." Except once people get the real picture, it won't be an app written for your iPhone, but a URL. "There's a site for that."

Comment: Everything? Including IDEs, Antivirus programs, iTunes etc. In my mind there are certain applications that can't be provided by a browser...

Comment: iTunes = grooveshark, antivirus = Housecall, IDE = flash/flex + bespin.  I know, they aren't perfect examples, but I did say in the next 10 years. I agree that it would be a tad hard to have a web-based app that ran a constant monitor for something like AV, but if everything is online, the browser could have a thin-app AV that handles doing security, and then you run Housecall (or the next big thing) if you get infected. And yes, Housecall uses java, but I think that's excused from my ideological ideas.

Comment: hmmm...you do have an interesting perspective Anthony. I guess the next ten years will show us which way things go....until then, I'm not 100% convinced that desktop apps will disappear....but I am certain they will become rarer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend learning the Lift framework. It's as easy to use as Rails, and it's based on a statically-typed language for the JVM, Scala. From the perspective of your background, Scala should be middling to easy to learn, and you'll be more likely to be comfortable with it than with a dynamic language.

In my opinion, you have a good chance of picking it up quickly, learn a lot about *good* practices in web development, and even expanding your programming horizons a bit.